# Does multiple \AtBeginDocument calls execute code in the appearing order

Tags: documentclass-writing

Let's say I have these two simple files

- `myclass.cls` :

  ```latex
  \LoadClass{article}
  \AtBeginDocument{\typeout{IN CLASS}}
  ```
- `myfile.tex`

  ```latex
  \AtBeginDocument{\typeout{BEFORE CLASS}}
  \documentclass{myclass}
  \AtBeginDocument{\typeout{AFTER CLASS}}
  \begin{document}
  empty
  \end{document}
  ```

When compiling `myfile.tex` I hoped to see messages in this order:

1. `BEFORE CLASS`
2. `IN CLASS`
3. `AFTER CLASS`

I rather got this order:

1. `IN CLASS`
2. `BEFORE CLASS`
3. `AFTER CLASS`

What did I miss?

Just for the sake of completeness, I get this result using `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian)` and `kpathsea version 6.3.2`.

Comment: the version of pdftex doesn't affect this but the version of latex does as it changed in recent releases see the hook system in ltnews32

Comment: Thank's I will look at it.
I was pretty sure that the order was respected some months ago. Your answer reassure me that I am not mad nor crazy.
It fears me too howeve: I may have to rewrite some of my classes and recompile a **lot** of files :-(

Anyway thank's for the link.

Comment: Any idea when the behavior of `\AtBeginDocument` changed?

Comment: @BrunoBEAUFILS: Oct 2020.

Comment: yes as I say, latexnews 32 (October 2020 release)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the hook management system `\AtBeginDocument` is an alias fro `\AddToHook{begindocument}` and all entries with the same label (defaulting to `toplevel` or your class name in this case) are executed together so they can be ordered by hook rules.

You can use the new optional argument to put the two calls in separate labels

```
\AtBeginDocument[A]{\typeout{BEFORE CLASS}}
\documentclass{myclass}
\AtBeginDocument[B]{\typeout{AFTER CLASS}}
\begin{document}
empty
\end{document}
```

produces

```
BEFORE CLASS
IN CLASS
AFTER CLASS
```

Comment: I just read lthooks-doc thank's to your link to ltnews32.

I do not get why in this answer you use different labels?

Using the same one in every `\AtBeginDocument` occurence in my two files (or using the `myclass` label only in the `.tex` file ones), gives the expected results.

If I get it right, it is a way to enforce not having the `\AtBeginDocument` in the class file to be treated separately from the others.

Am I right?

Is using the `myclass` label considered *bad* usage of hooks?

Comment: I re-read section 2.1.4 (*The top-level label*) and 2.3 (*On the order of hook code execution*) of [lthooks-doc.pdf](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/lthooks-doc.pdf). I think I get the point. With the hook system all we need to do to respect order of appearance is to remove them from the `top-level` label which is always executed last. Any other one, even different is sufficient .

Comment: if you put them both in A then `A` will be done first then `myclass` so you will get  BEFORE CLASS, AFTER CLASS, IN CLASS @BrunoBEAUFILS

Comment: Thank's for the clarification. Order is using alphabectic order? Is using `myclass` as label outside the class file itself a good practice in such case?